# Generate XML file from model data

Tags: python, xml, django, serialization

I need to write model data (`CharField`s only) to an XML file to contain the data for a flash file.  I am new to this, and the process is a little unclear to me for doing this in django.  I am creating an xml file, and then writing the text data to the file (as is done with the csv module, but to xml).  A very simplified xml file should result for the flash file to read, ie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<textFields>
     <textField id="0" text="HELLO WORLD" />
     <textField id="1" text="HELLO EARTH" />
     ...
</textFields>
```

1. I am using a serializer to write the xml data from the model:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('xml', myModel.objects.filter(instanceIwantTowrite), fields=('fieldName'))
```

2. I then create file using `core.files`:

```
from django.core.files import File    
f = open('/path/to/new/dir/content.xml', 'w')
myfile = File(f)
```

3. Write File data and close:

```
myfile.write(data)

myfile.close()
```

This works so far, although the xml output contains the fields for the object "django-objects" etc, and I will have to see if I can interpret this in ActionScript easily for the flash file.  I would prefer to define the xml field names manually like in the csv module. As I am new to django and python, I am wondering if there is an easier, simpler way to do this?

**Note:** In serializer I use filter on the model objects because using `get` for the model instance returns an `object not iterable` error.  In fact I filter it twice to get a single instance, seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: I'm not clear about the XML format you want. Is a `textField` element equal to a single row in the database, each with a single field? If so what's the `id` number referring to? If not, how are you differentiating between rows?

Comment: Also, have you considered JSON as a serialization format? It's much easier to both create and consume.

Comment: Yes, textField would be a single charField entry in the DB (each db entry field to fill a textfield in a flash file). Sorry the id was a bit confusing then, the idea is that there are multiple textfields in the flash file, so the id's correspond to different charFields in the model.  They should be different model charFields.  Im looking into JSON now, normally Ive used xml with AS3, it seems so far that JSON would require an AS3 library import, and for this app that's not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have two possible solutions here:

**1.**

You can extend base django xml serializer(`django.core.serializers.xml_serializer.Serializer`) and modify it so it will return data in your structure. You could then run ex.

```
YourSerializer('xml', myModel.objects.filter(instanceIwantTowrite), fields=('fieldName'))
```

and it will output data in your structure.

**2.**

Write simple function that will render template with your data structure and return xml data in your format:

Python code

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def my_serialize(query_set):
    xml = render_to_string('xml_template.xml', {'query_set': query_set})

    return xml
```

Template xml_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<textFields>
     {% for object in query_set %}
     <textField id="{{ object.pk }}" text="{{ object.my_field }}" />
     {% endfor %}
</textFields>
```

Comment: Ok, option 2 looks like the optimal solution to this, so i can define the xml structure at will using render_to_string and a predefined template (which could be even just a text file i suppose).  Then I just use the file.write() method with 'xml' as the content... ok great, I will try to implement this option, thanks!

Comment: Yes, template is a text file.

Comment: Brilliant. Works without the fuss. +1

Comment: Thanks, trying to read the automatically generated XML file from the Django serializer almost gave me a seizure... Option 2 works great! +1

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic approach to solving this problem, you can avoid templates by using a simple duck punch on Models, and serialize any deep object graph to XML using ElementTree.

Here's how I solved it:

Monkey patch/duck punch models in your Model.py like:

```
if hasattr(models.Model, "to_element")==False:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    def to_element(self):
        ele = ET.Element(self.__class__.__name__)
        for field in self._meta.fields:
            ele.attrib[field.attname]=str(getattr(self,field.attname))
        return ele
    models.Model.to_element = to_element
```

This adds a method to Model which creates an Element instance containing the fields from the model that you care about, without the django cruft.

Then, to construct your xml document, just do this:

```
dealer = Dealer.objects.get(id=dealer_id)
makes = DealerMake.objects.filter(dealer=dealer)

root = dealer.to_element()
for make in makes:
    root.append(make.to_element())

xml = ET.tostring(root)
print xml
```

With this approach you can get a nicely formatted xml document with all django model fields as attributes, and construct an n-level deep hierarchy. Each xml node will be named the same as the model class.