# how to display rendered values in xml format

Tags: xml, django

I have this in my template file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entries>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <entry>{{ entry.entry_id }}</entry>
    {{ endfor }}
</entries>
```

and this in my view:

```
...
return render(request, 'entries.xml', {'entries': entries})
```

When i want to display data it displayed like this:

```
1 2 3 4 ...
```

But the desiered result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entries>
    <entry>1</entry>
    <entry>2</entry>
    <entry>3</entry>
    <entry>4</entry>
    ...
</entries>
```

How to display all of the xml tree with tags in a browser?

Comment: Could you clarify, what is the desired output and where are you displaying your data?

Comment: why not use http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/ and format type as xml ... or check this question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829442/generate-xml-file-from-model-data

Comment: @boltsfrombluesky: how to use format type ?

Comment: i just tried your code and it looks fine .. if you are using chrome press ctrl+u and see the source it displays xml correctly

Comment: @boltsfrombluesky: yes but iwant to display it directly in the browser not viewing source code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your xml file must be like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <test>{% for entry in entries %}
         <entries>
            <entry>{{ entry.id }}</entry>
         </entries>{% endfor %}
    </test>
```

**To view this data in a browser, you must indicate the content type**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def view_in_xml(request):
    response = render_to_response('robots.xml', {'entries': YourModel.objects.all(),})
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml;'
    return response
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried this .. but i think this will get you what you want in  your browser but this is not real xml

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?&gt;<br/>
&lt;entries&gt; <br/>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;entry&gt;{{ entry.entry_id }}&lt;/entry&gt; <br/>
    {{ endfor }}
&lt;/entries&gt;
```

Comment: i would suggest you to use your original code and use some chrome addon .. or use IE it displays xml by default .. also if you need coloring effects you need to add more html tags to it ..

Comment: i think in the render args there is somthing like mimetype or aplication-type like argument for render() i cant find it !